# Promise data and exception handling

Tags: javascript, exception, promise, catch-block

I am confused with the use of promise, specifically of its way of data manipulation (passing values from block to block) and exception handling (bubbling up the error). I am trying to learn a right way to use promise and to handle error, something like

```
Error: A caught error.
    at promiseTwo()
    at promiseOne()
    at subprocess()
    at mainprocess()
```

Here are my two attempts in implementing them:

**Attempt 1:** Clumsy, deeply nested, and errors are uncaught.

```
var subprocess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        promiseOne().then(data1 => {
            // Some code with data1, throw some error
            promiseTwo().then(data2 => {
                // Some code with data1n2, throw some error
                promiseThree().then(data3 => {
                    // Data manipulation with data1, data2, and data3
                    return resolve(<...>)
                }).catch(err3 => { throw err3 })
            }.catch(err2n3 => { throw err2n3 })          // >>> ERR: Cannot get err3.
        }.catch(err1n2n3 => { return reject(err1n2n3) }) // >>> ERR: Cannot get err3 or err2.
    }
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    subprocess().then(data => {
        // TODO
    }).catch(allErr => { return reject(allErr) }
}
```

**Attempt 2:** Unable to use data from previous promise block.

```
var subprocess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        promiseOne()
        .then(data1 => {
            // Some code with data1, throw some error
            return promiseTwo()
        })
        .then(data2 => {
            // Some code with data1n2, throw some error
            // >>> ERR: Cannot get data1
            return promiseThree()
        })
        .then(data3 => {
            // Data manipulation with data1, data2, and data3
            // >>> ERR: Cannot get data1 and data2
            return resolve(<...>)
        })
        .catch(err1n2n3 => { 
            return reject(err1n2n3) 
        })
    }
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    subprocess().then(data => {
        // Some code, throw some error
    }).catch(allErr => { return reject(allErr) }
}
```

*Note:* Some of the promise block (i.e. `promiseOne`, `promiseTwo`, etc.) are pre-defined so I do not have control over what data they will return. I am sure there are more errors in the attempts (e.g. if `return`ing a function is a right way to do it).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Check this article on concurrent promises https://www.codementor.io/@edafeadjekeemunotor/building-a-concurrent-promise-queue-with-javascript-1ano2eof0v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this kind of situation, you can combine promises and async-await together.

From the question, it seems we have three promises and one function that executes and handle them.

You can try something like this -

```
const subProcess = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Using IIFE ( You shouldn't put async keyword on promise callbac )
    (async () => {
      // Use of try catch to handle the errors
      try { 
        await promiseOne()
        await promiseTwo()
        await promiseThree()
        // Additional code if need after them
      } catch(err){
        // Handle error ( all three promise error will be transferred here )
      }
    })()

  })
}
```

The above code waits for the promises to execute one by one and also catch error from all three promises if any.

And as @samuei mentioned, you can also use Promise.all() in this.

```
const subProcess = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Using IIFE ( You shouldn't put async keyword on promise callbac )
    (async () => {
      // Use of try catch to handle the errors
      try { 
        const myPromises = [promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree];
        const res = await Promise.all(myPromises);
        // Additional code if need after them
      } catch(err){
        // Handle error ( all three promise error will be transferred here )
      }
    })()

  })
}
```

And if you don't want to use async-await then you can do something like this as well

```
const subProcess = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const myPromises = [];
    const myPromises = [promiseOne, promiseTwo, promiseThree];

    Promise.all(myPromises)
    .then(res => {
      // Handle the response
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle the error
    })

  })
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all` does seem like a nice way to summarise the async functions. However, when I am trying to synchronise async function, is it possible to use any returned result in, say, promiseOne, and pass it as parameter in promiseTwo?

Comment: Yes, if you are using async-await then that is very easy. Something like this
`const res = await promiseOne(); await promiseTwo(res); await promiseThree() `

Comment: You can see, i am passing res from promiseOne to the promiseTwo.

Comment: Thanks! Just a follow up question. Why an IIFE is needed to contain the try-catch block? Can I simply use try-catch without it?

Comment: I used IIFE so that I can use async-await and not try-catch. You shouldn't put the async keyword on the promise like this `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {})`
It is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which lets you set a series of promises in motion, then deal with the results when they are all resolved.